# Can no include a simple javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to include some very simple javascript file in my php file. I have a index.php where I include an header.php and a footer.php to turn my code more modular.

I include my javascript in footer.php and consequently I include footer.php in the end of index.php. The path for my javascript file is: js/myscript.js

My header.php:

```
<?php
include "inc/conn.php";
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION["user"])){
        echo $_SESSION["user"];
    }
?>
<nav>
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION["user"])){
        echo "<ol>";
        echo "<li><a href='#'>".$_SESSION["user"]."</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='inc/logout.php'>Logout</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='messages.php'>Messages</a></li>";
        echo "</ol>";
    }
?>
</nav>
```

My index.php:

```
 <?php
include "header.php";
?>
    <label for="regist">Regist</label>
    <form id="regist" action="inc/regist.php" method="post" name="regist">
        <label for="registUsername">username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="registUsername" name="username" pattern="[a-z]">
        <label for="registPassword">password</label>
        <input type="password" id="registPassword" name="password">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Regist">
    </form>

    <label for="login">Login</label>
    <form id="login" action="inc/login.php" method="post" name="login">
        <label for="loginUsername">username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="loginUsername" name="username">
        <label for="loginPassword">password</label>
        <input type="password" id="loginPassword" name="password">
        <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit">
    </form>
<?php
include "footer.php";
?>
```

My footer.php:

```
</body>
<script scr="js/myscript.js"></script>
</html>
```

For the purpose of just trying include a javascript file my javascript is just:

```
alert("test");
```

If I put in footer.php like this it works:

```
</body>
<script >
    alert("test");
</script>
</html>
```

If I put like this it does not work anymore and I can not find the reason why:

```
</body>
<script scr="js/myscript.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing can go before `DOCTYPE` and `body` must come after `head`. You can include content into the `head` or the `body`.

Comment: Voting to close because the problem is caused by a typo. The abbreviation of *source* is `src` not `scr` (which is the file extension for Windows 3.1 screen savers). Use a validator: https://validator.nu/

Comment: Use browser console for errors please

Comment: `<script scr="js/myscript.js"></script>` should be `<script src="js/myscript.js"></script>`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was jus a typo and it won't be useful to others.

Comment: @Lukas — It is generally a good idea to hang around after asking a question in case you get immediate responses to it (which is very common in for questions in the tags you have selected).

Comment: where's your body opening tag <body> ?

Comment: @Vishwa — That tag is defined as optional in the HTML spec.

Comment: @Quentin I asked because I see body tag only being closed without opening, thats weird

Comment: @Vishwa — The body element is started implicitly and ended explicitly. This is fine. Both tags are independently optional.

Comment: thank you for clarification, thought it's a bad practice to include just one

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It was just a typo, I saw in the comments that this question should be closed since it was just a typo and it won't be useful to others. I just do not find an option to close it...

Answer (score -4):

first of all try to put your script just before the end of your body

Comment: While having the script after the end of the body is forbidden by the rules of HTML, fixing this issue won't solve the problem.